# Run application on server by application on client computer

Tags: java, client, client-server, server

I have an Linux server, and i have 2 Java applications.

1- `ServerApp.jar`. This application is on my server.

2- `PcApp.jar`. This application is on my computer.

May i make `ServerApp.jar` application run, by click on button in `PcApp.jar` application?

Comment: @reto i mean make `ServerApp.jar` run, by click on button in `PcApp.jar`

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to download and execute the remote jars at client place.

But for your problem of invoking some operation on remote machine itself, you'll have to fall back to RMI or services implementation on server side and trigger them inside PcApp.jar